# MYSQL doesn't work for me on a simple task

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I use MYSQLWorkbench 6.1 on a localhost mysql server.

If I run `SELECT 'run';` I get a correct text output in the console.

If I run this simple query instead:

```
IF (1=1) THEN
        SELECT 'run';
END IF
```

I get syntax errno 1064. What's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "BEGIN ... END syntax is used for writing compound statements, **which can appear within stored programs**". You are using that syntax outside of a stored procedure.

Please read the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/begin-end.html

Comment: Without BEGIN END doesn't work also. So what's your solution for that mister? http://i.imgur.com/lPADfkk.png

Comment: There must be someone that READ the MANUAL from top to bottom... I can't believe there isn't one!

Comment: You `IF … THEN … ELSE` syntax is strange too; You need to use the function `IF()` inside a `SELECT` statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if